# Avoiding concurrent access of data in MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, concurrency, queue

We are developing a C# application that used to work as a single instance application. Now we need to change it to be a multi-user application, meaning the GUI front-end will be run on multiple workstations while accessing a single MS SQL Server 2008 R2 data store.

Part of the work this application manages is queue based, meaning there's a pool of workitems (the list of workitems is in a single SQL table) from which each user can "take" the next available workitem. What I want to accomplish are the following:

- once a workitem is "taken" by a user, no other user should have access to it in any way (including reading) until the first user finished working,
- handle timeouts (user goes home for the weekend while workitem is taken) and frozen clients (reset button is pressed on the station while workitem is taken).

I know this is a rather general question (much rather a research), so I'm not expecting a detailed solution, but useful links, best practices and/or some literature to read on the subject. Any help is really appreciated since I'm completely lost where to start.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: the "taken" can just be a bool (or even better, a nullable int representing the user Id of the user that has taken the task), then you could easily query `.Where(x => x.TakenByUserId == null)`

Comment: Rui: nothing, just research. I'd like to obtain some proven concepts - if there's any - before plunging into writing code.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this done with a transactional resource lock table or column.  For example, you assign the record to someone (be it by setting a user ID or some other mechanism) and you simultaneously set a timestamped record as to when that resource was locked.  When accessing the data, be it querying it or trying to update it, you first check this lock table/column to make sure it's available.  If not, you don't take the changes.

This also supports timeouts then.  If the timestamp is too old, the lock is released.  You can automatically assumed release if the timestamp is too old, or you can write a scheduled service that will check for expired locks and unlock them.  I'd prefer the second way, as it is less costly to check if a lock is there (boolean logic for row exists or if field value exists [i.e. is not null]).  But I've seen it done both ways.

Comment: This was the general idea I thought of, but is there a documentation somewhere that explains pros/cons of the approaches? I'd really like to read about some production proven concepts.

Comment: Not that I know of.  Dig deep and I'm sure you'll find something.  But the solution is pretty specialized for the need.  For example, most resource locks I've seen still allow reading and some light interactions, like commenting, etc; just not assignment and such.  So really, it's up to you in the end to pick the approach.